# Android: negative coordinates in ViewGroup and touch rectangles

Tags: android, touch, coordinates, rectangles, viewgroup

I come from an ActionScript/Flash/AIR background and I'm new to the Android View hierarchy. Given that, I found something very odd about ViewGroup and it's coordinate system.

Let's say we have the following parent/child relationship inside the main Activity View which extends RelativeView (or basically some group layout that allows absolute coordinates and scale):

```
circle1 = new ImageView(context);
circle1.setImageBitmap(...);
circle2 = new ImageView(context);
circle2.setImageBitmap(...);
cont = new RelativeView(context);

cont.addView(circle1);
cont.addView(circle2);
this.addView(cont);
```

The idea is to create a container which is centered on the main view and to center two circles inside of the container. This allows the container to be animated, grouping the two circles.

```
cont.setX(getWidth() / 2);
cont.setY(getHeight() / 2);
circle1.setX(-circle1.getWidth() / 2);
circle1.setY(-circle1.getHeight() / 2);
circle2.setX(-circle2.getWidth() / 2);
circle2.setY(-circle2.getHeight() / 2);
```

Doing negative coordinates inside a ViewGroup, I immediately noticed that 'cont' clips them at the [0, 0] coordinate and cont.setClipChildren(false); has to be called. I'm guessing this is a bad idea, because it looks like a optimization for the invalidate() area. After disabling the clipping, the result renders as expected, but there is another problem:

[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHNkU.png)

Adding a touch event listener to circle2 returns a bogus touch rectangle (marked in purple) instead of the expected one (marked in cyan) which should be staring at the negative [X, Y] offset of circle2. The resulting rectangle starts at [0, 0] of 'cont' and ends at [circle2X + circle2W, circle2Y + circle2H] as if it's clipped at [0, 0] of 'cont'.

I know that you can solve the issue by not using negative coordinates, but that's not really a good solution if you are porting from ActionScript where negative coordinates make perfect sense (as in any real world coordinate system) and touch rectangles are calculated correctly in the DisplayObjectContainer class.

So what other solutions are there?

- Should a custom ViewGroup class be created and what has to be done there?
- Is there a magical setting which can allow touch rectangles of children Views not to be clipped at [0, 0] of the parent ViewGroup?
- Something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this to do with android:clipchildren which is false by default?

Comment: Derp,  never mind, managed to gloss over part of the question

Comment: when i do a: Rect out = new Rect(); circle2.getHitRect(out); "out" contains the correct values of the hitRect for circle2. (i.e. nagative values for "left" and "top"). it seems as if the parent ViewGroup is simply not allowing touches at a negative offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `View#scrollTo` to move the origin so that your content is shown entirely within the View's bounding rect.

Many things in the Android UI toolkit rely on the measured and laid out bounds of Views being accurate. In general you don't want to go against the grain here.

Comment: thanks. your solution is valid one - so i'm marking it as such. once the scrollTo() is applied the touch hit rectangle does work, but the side effect of course is that the whole contents of the ViewGroup are moved (scrolled). so to compensate for that the [X, Y] of 'cont' has to be also adjusted. this is close to complexity but less complex (LOC wise) to one of the solutions i already knew of and already mentioned in the OP - which is to position 'cont' based on size of its larger child and not use negative coordinates. sadly, such design patterns make it more involving for the end developer.